# Batch Apex Class Invoked From Before Delete Trigger is not deleting Files Attached to accounts

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I have written a batch class to delete the files related to an account whenever an account is being deleted. When I have tried the same code and logic without batch class it works fine. But in batch class, it is not deleting the file from ContentDocument which I can see from the Files tab.

I am passing the Account IDs from the trigger FYI.

I can see the debug log from the finish method, but I don't see the debug logs from the execute method.

Trigger Code:

```
Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Account acc: Trigger.old){
    accIds.add(acc.Id);
}
DeleteAccRelatedFilesBatch darfb = new DeleteAccRelatedFilesBatch(accIds);
Database.executeBatch(darfb);
```

Batch class code:

```
public class DeleteAccRelatedFilesBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    Set<Id> accountIds;

    public DeleteAccRelatedFilesBatch(Set<Id> accountIds){
        this.accountIds = accountIds;
    }

    public Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query ='SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :accountIds';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocLinks = (List<ContentDocumentLink>)scope;
            System.debug('size of the list >> '+scope.size());
            Set<Id> contentDocIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: contentDocLinks){
                contentDocIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
            }
            Database.DeleteResult[] drCdl = Database.delete(contentDocLinks, false);
            System.debug('drCdl >> '+drCdl);
            List<ContentDocument> contentDocList;
            if(!contentDocIds.isEmpty()){
                contentDocList = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :contentDocIds];
                Database.DeleteResult[] drCd = Database.delete(contentDocList, false);
                System.debug('drCd >> '+drCd);
            }
            System.debug('Successfully deleted related files of the accounts');
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('came to the finish method');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The query won't return any records, because the accounts will have already been deleted by the time your batch class has run. Instead, query for those files in the trigger, and use a batchable, if you'd like, to delete those files afterwards:

```
Database.executeBatch(
  new DeleteFilesBatch(
    [select id from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid = :trigger.old
  ]
);
```

```
public class DeleteFilesBatch implements Database.Batchable<ContentDocumentLink> {
  public DeleteFilesBatch(ContentDocumentLink[] records) {
    links = records;
  }
  ContentDocumentLink[] links;
  public Iterable<ContentDocumentLink> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return links;
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, ContentDocumentLink[] records) {
    delete records;
    Set<Id> contentDocumentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink link: records) {
      contentDocumentIds.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    for(ContentDocumentLink link: [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = :contentDocumentIds]) {
       contentDocumentIds.remove(link.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = :contentDocumentIds];
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
  }
}
```

While this does limit you to just 50,000 documents, that should be sufficient for most orgs.

Answer (score 2):

If the `execute` of your batch class is not running, but the `finish` is, it means that the query in the `start` is returning zero results.

Your batch class will be running asynchronously, so it will be running after the accounts have been deleted. This will mean the query in your batch will return nothing.